# Stream Filter on another Stream and Count

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to filter a stream based on another stream and get a count of all matching entries.

I have tried the following and various other combinations but it is not working as expected.

The idea is:

- for every number from 0 to 256 (stream 1)
- see if the number appears in another list (stream 2) and if it does
- count the number of appearances divided by the total number of elements (which is 18) in stream 2.
- If it does not appear, collect 0.

This is basically finding the frequency of numbers in stream 1 based on occurrences in stream 2.

Stream 2 is

```
int[] chars = {332, 255, 271, 232, 194, 39, 162, 89, 200, 126, 225, 218, 42, 237, 87, 63, 63, 229};
```

Expected output for the below code is:

```
[0,0,0,...,1/18for39,0,0,1/18for42,0,0,...,2/18for63,...,1/18for87,0,1/18for89,...1/18for126,0,0,...1/18for162,0,0,...,etc..1/18for255,0]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> predicate = (d, f) -> Integer.valueOf(d)
    .equals(Integer.valueOf(f));

List<Double> fractions = chars.filter(value -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 256)
    .anyMatch(nbr -> predicate.test(value, nbr)))
    .count()
    .map(x -> x)
    .mapToDouble(x -> x / chars.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: another challenge with your code is getting to know the size of the stream while consuming it in the same operation such as `chars.filter....` and trying to get size incorrectly from `chars.size()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid iterating the source 256 times. In case of a Stream, you can’t process it more than once anyway, but even if you have a source that allows iterating it multiple times, you shouldn’t do it that often, when avoidable.

If you want to make it look like a single Stream operation, you can do, e.g.

```
int[] chars = {332, 255, 271, 232, 194, 39, 162, 89, 200, 126, 225, 218, 42, 237, 87, 63, 63, 229};
```

```
List<Double> fractions = Arrays.stream(chars).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()),
        map -> {
            double total = map.values().stream().mapToInt(Long::intValue).sum();
            return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 256)
                .mapToObj(i -> map.getOrDefault(i, 0L)/total)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }));
```

But using a Stream or “one operation” isn’t an end in itself.

If you want a simple and efficient solution, consider

```
int[] counts = new int[257];
for(int c: chars) if(c >= 0 && c <= 256) counts[c]++;
double total = chars.length;
List<Double> fractions
    = Arrays.stream(counts).mapToObj(c -> c/total).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it a little different, being a bit more general to the problem at hand:

```
IntStream idents = ...; // Your 0-256
IntStream input = ...; // your random numbers

//Generate a map of input numbers to how often they occur
Map<Integer, Long> freq = input.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
//No need for the stream's source, use the map
long total = freq.values().stream().reduce(0L, Long::sum); // your 18
```

With our frequency map, it becomes easy to create what we want. I did an answer with what I would advise, as well as one that satisfies your requirements:

```
//Generating the 0-256 array in double form
double[] result = idents.mapToDouble(i -> freq.getOrDefault(i, 0) / (double) total).toArray();
```

To be honest, I don't see much point in doing this over just using the frequency map to determine the information you need:

```
//Find the fraction for 39:
double value = freq.getOrDefault(39, 0) / (double) total;

//Find only the values in range:
Predicate<Integer> inRange = i -> i >= 0 && i <= 256;
freq.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> inRange.test(e.getKey())); //you now have a stream of the valid frequencies

//Or the values out of range
....filter(e -> inRange.negate().test(e.getKey()))
```

If the input is empty, you can also just return the array right away. Let me know if there's another example case I didn't cover

Comment: Thanks for reviewing it, I tend to write my answers up on the phone and test them up later, _typically_ they're not that egregious errors.

Comment: Mind that with the `Map<Integer, Long>`, the subsequent `mapToInt(i -> i)` doesn’t work as `i` will be `Long`. You have to use, e.g. `mapToInt(Long::intValue)`, instead.

Comment: Considering it's a #sum of longs into a long to begin with, might as well just use LongStream or #reduce. Fixed.

Comment: Well, it’s a sum of longs, but we know that it can’t be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Still, just summing the longs has a point, though `reduce(0L, Long::sum)` bears some boxing overhead, unlike `mapToLong(l -> l).sum()`. Note that in my solution, I declared `total` as `double`, which eliminates the need to type-cast it in the later processing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other solutions(which are efficient in terms of iterating through the elements of the given stream) but closer to your existing attempt would be to make use of input as an array for being able to use the size dimension while processing them and instead of performing `anyMatch`, just plainly `filter`ing and counting the elements to further perform the manipulation for average as:

```
int[] chars = new int[]{332, 255, 271, 232, 194, 39, 162, 89, 200, 126, 225, 218, 42, 237, 87, 63, 63, 229};
List<Double> fractions = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 256)
        .mapToLong(value -> Arrays.stream(chars).filter(f -> value == f).count())
        .mapToDouble(x -> (double) x / chars.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like this approach as all operations are done in one shot which was my goal. However, when I run this I get all zeros in my fractions list which is incorrect, maybe I am doing something wrong. Also, please note that 63 appears twice in the input so its frequency should be 2/18. Thanks.

Comment: @suhasghorp edited the answer to ensure that the count is matched based on the stream from the input `chars`.

Comment: `.mapToDouble(x -> x / chars.length)` perform an integer division (always yielding zero), before converting the result to `double`. You need `.mapToDouble(x -> (double)x / chars.length).boxed()` instead. Or you change the preceding `mapToLong` to `mapToDouble` and `mapToDouble` to `map`.